# django model ForeignKey relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 3 models User, Lesson, Company

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Company(models.Model):
    pass  

class Lesson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

How can I add one lesson for two companies

Comment: Is it necessary for you to keep ForeignKey instead of using ManyToMany ?

Comment: yes it's on the live project

Comment: Then try concept from my answer and let me know of the results

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: What exactly didn't work ? Can you provide with some traceback ?

Comment: company = Company.objects.get(email__contains=['dev.com']) 
[company.lesson_set.add(lesson) for lesson in user.lessons.all()]

but it doesn't save anything in db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167872/discussion-between-sipan-and-madi7).

Answer (score 3):

If a `Company` has multiple `Lesson`s and you also want a `Lesson` to have multiple `Company`s, you should use a `ManyToManyField`

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(User)
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)

c1 = Company()
c1.save()
c2 = Company()
c2.save()

l1 = Lesson()
l1.companies.add(c1, c2)
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can do  with Foreignkey relation

Comment: If the many relationship exists on just the `Company` end, then you could use a `ForeignKey` as neverwalkaloner describes. However, if you also want many `Lesson`s per `Company` (as your opening example shows) then you would need a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: What kind of problems  I would have if I change to ManyToManyField in the live DB

Comment: If you were to make this change and then make the migrations, Django would introduce an extra transparent join table to support the many to many relationship. This would likely need to be manually populated with data based on existing foreign key relationships. This is definitely something you should do in development first (ideally with a copy of the live db) to fully understand the implications.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should put `ForeignKey` to `Company` model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    lesson = models.Foreignkey(lesson)
```

Create a new company object, and add it to the lesson:

```
>>> c1 = Comapany(attr="blah", attr2="foo")
>>> l1.comapany_set.add(c1)
```

and you can add a list of company objects to lesson

```
>>> l1.comapany_set.add(*company_objs)
```

now you can access companies related to specific lesson with `company_set`attribut:

```
lesson.company_set.all()
```

also you can now assign one lesson to differen companies:

```
company1.lesson = lesson
company2.lesson = lesson
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via shell: `python manage.py shell`

```
a = Company.objects.first()
b = Company.objects.last()
c = Lesson.objects.first()

a.lesson_set.add(c)
b.lesson_set.add(c)
```

You can also use: `lessons` instead of: `lesson_set` if you change models with: `related_name`

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='lessons')
```

And from now you can use it like:

```
a.lessons.add(c)
b.lessons.add(c)
```